# Create a frame using FlowLayout

Tags: java, button, panel, frame, flowlayout

Okay, so I'm having some trouble with my Programming Exercise today.

The Exercise text goes like this:

> (Use the **FlowLayout** manager) Write a program that meets the following requirements:
>
> - Create a frame and set its layout to **FlowLayout**
> - Create two panels and add them to the frame
> - Each panel contains three buttons. The panel uses **FlowLayout**

The buttons should be named "Button 1", "Button 2" and so on.

I think I'm having some trouble with adding the **panels** to the **frame** because when i run the program, it shows an *empty* **frame**.

*Here is the code i have.*

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Exercise12_1 extends JFrame {

    public Exercise12_1() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Exercise 12_1 ");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Create two panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Add three buttons to each panel
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 1 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 2 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 3 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 4 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 5 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 6 "));

        // Add panels to frame
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.add(panel2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise12_1 frame = new Exercise12_1();
        frame.setTitle(" Exercise 12_1 ");
        frame.setSize(600, 100);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if some of you took your time to help me out here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main method creates a frame:

```
Exercise12_1 frame = new Exercise12_1();
```

and then makes it visible.

And the constructor of this 'Exercise12_1' frame creates **another** frame, and adds panel to this other frame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Exercise 12_1 ");
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

The constructor shouldn't create another frame. It should add the panels to `this`: the frame being constructed, and that will then be made visible.

Also, you should not use `setSize()`, but `pack()`, to make the frame have the most appropriate size based on the preferred size of all the components it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Exercise12_1 extends JFrame {

    public Exercise12_1() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Exercise 12_1 ");
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Create two panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Add three buttons to each panel
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 1 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 2 "));
        panel1.add(new JButton(" Button 3 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 4 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 5 "));
        panel2.add(new JButton(" Button 6 "));

        // Add panels to frame
        this.add(panel1);
        this.add(panel2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise12_1 frame = new Exercise12_1();
        frame.setTitle(" Exercise 12_1 ");
        frame.setSize(600, 100);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use use such code like this.getContentPane().add(panel1); to add Panel.

Change

```
frame.add(panel1);
frame.add(panel2);
```

To

```
this.getContentPane().add(panel1);
this.getContentPane().add(panel2);
```

and it will be working then.

Comment: Thank you very much, i added the code you provided and now it runs nicely.